# Is it safe to modify thunderbird mail box from python?

Tags: python, thunderbird

I would like to compare and merge several mail boxes managed by `thunderbird` (because they contain a lot of duplicated messages). They are in the `mbox` format.

My first idea was to use the standard [mailbox](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.htm) python module. It can easily read messages from `mbox` but I'm not sure that modifying the mail boxes would work: it could mess the index (MSF files) or other `thunderbird` internals. Of course, `thunderbird` will be closed and the mail boxes locked.

Does anybody have experience on that?

I guess there exists some python binding for the `thunderbird` API. Would it be safer to use that?

Comment: As a precaution, I would leave the messages on the server for a couple of days while you mess around with Python. That way, if anything goes wrong, you can simply download them.

Comment: You're 100% right! However, in my case it's a but hard because I mainly use a yahoo address with POP3 access: some messages are no longer the servers and if I'm correct, POP3 cannot copy messages back to the server (part of the motivation for this is to clean my local mess and then move to IMAP access). However, I wanted to run the first tests on a copy of the account.

Comment: It should be possible to copy your whole profile folder to another location and start Thunderbird using thunderbird -P profile . This way you can try anything you want to on the copy without touching the "live" data. NOTE: This assumes you're using POP. Don't try this using an IMAP account because any change you manage to make to an IMAP account will either be undone as soon as you connect to the server or any errors that survive that will probably affect the server. Not good!

Comment: Cont'd: You could test in an IMAP environment if you set Thunderbird to offline mode or, better yet, disabled your Internet connection while testing with the alternate profile. It would be very easy to accidentally switch Thunderbird back into online mode and only a disabled connection will protect you from that. (If you're good, you could probably do that just with iptables/firewall without taking your whole connection down.)